# R dplyr group by one column and filter rows according another two columns

Tags: r, dplyr

Here is an example of my data frame. And i want the results grouped by column A (colA), and then filter rows where only words having the following 4 types of values at the same time ("colB == 1 & colC == 1", "colB == 2 & colC == 2","colB == 1 & colC == 2","colB == 2 & colC == 1") are selected. I suspect that this would involve combined use of AND and OR condition, but I am not sure how to do it.

```
colA  colB colC
become  2   1
become  2   1
become  2   1
borrow  1   2
break   1   2
break   1   1
bridge  1   1
build   1   2
buy     1   2
buy     2   2
buy     2   1
buy     1   1
buy     1   1
```

Therefore, in the above example, only rows of "buy" were selected. The output should be something like this:

```
colA  colB colC
buy     1   2
buy     2   2
buy     2   1
buy     1   1
buy     1   1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After grouping by 'colA', `filter` the rows by checking if `all` the elements in the `vector` (`c('11', ...., '21')`) are there `%in%` the `paste`d the 'colB', 'colC'

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df1 %>% 
   group_by(colA) %>% 
   filter( all(c('11', '22', '12', '21') %in% str_c(colB, colC)))
# A tibble: 5 x 3
# Groups:   colA [1]
#  colA   colB  colC
#  <chr> <int> <int>
#1 buy       1     2
#2 buy       2     2
#3 buy       2     1
#4 buy       1     1
#5 buy       1     1
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(colA = c("become", "become", "become", "borrow", 
"break", "break", "bridge", "build", "buy", "buy", "buy", "buy", 
"buy"), colB = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L), colC = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -13L))
```